# C++ Program producing false result... What is the cause?

Tags: c++, pointers

Something is wrong with this code as it modifies an array. All elements are assigned 0. But why ?? Here's the question of program:

Write a function named "subtotal" takes as its arguments the following:

(1) an array of floating point values;

(2) an integer that tells the number of cells in the array.

The function should replace the contents of each cell with the sum of the contents of all the cells in the
original array from the left end to the cell in question.

Thus, for example, if the array passed to the
function looks like this:

[0] [1] [2] [3] [4]

5.8 | 2.6 | 9.1 | 3.4 | 7.0

then when the function returns, the array will have been changed so that it looks like this:

[0] [1] [2] [3] [4]

5.8 | 8.4 | 17.5 | 20.9 | 27.9

because 5.8 + 2.6 = 8.4 and 5.8 + 2.6 + 9.1 = 17.5 and so on. Note that the contents of cell [0] are not
changed. The function should not return a value.

And here is the program which I've made:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void subtotal(float*,int);

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of cells: ";
    cin >> n;
    float* cell;
    cell = new float[n];
    cout << "Enter the elements: ";

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> *(cell + i);

    subtotal(cell, n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << *(cell + i) << "|";
    delete[] cell;  
}

void subtotal(float* cell, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        float sum = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            sum += *(cell + j); 
        }
        *(cell + i) = sum;
    }   
}
```

Comment: _new_ and _delete_ normally aren't used in C++ programms. Use _std::vector_ instead. This also obsoletes the requirement of passing a pointer as representation for an array to a function, since this can be replaced with a reference to said _vector_ or, better, use iterators for a generic solution. When handling array sizes and indices, you should also use size_t instead of plain int.

Comment: *"new and delete normally aren't used in C++ programms."*  WTF!? `new` and `delete` are absolutely *key* to most C++ programs.  Certain uses can be avoided with structures like vectors, but they're still a key part of C++.

Comment: @abelenky With C++11 we have stuff like smart pointers which do make the c-style `new` and `delete` obsolete.

Comment: @abelenky: Yes, true. In 1998 anyway. Today I rarely find myself writing the occasional `new`. But `delete`? I do not recall the last time typing this into a code editor (other than explicitly removing compiler-generated class members).

Comment: C does not have `new` and `delete`.  Perhaps you mean `malloc` and `free`?  
But what do you think smart-pointers call?  Smart-pointers are just wrappers that call  `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @abelenky: You said *"key to most C++ **programs**"*. Smart pointers are library code, not programs. In programs, there's hardly ever a reason to call `new`, and virtually no reason to call `delete`. And kim366 was referring to C-style manual memory management, not that C had operators `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @abelenky : fundamentally disagree.  I hardly *ever* have to use new, and if I am using delete, there is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Why using nested loop? You can use only one loop so that the you'll iterate once is enough as long as you want only sum the consecutive elements so change the function `subtotal` to:

```
void subtotal(float* cell, int n)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) // `n - 1` to avoid outband 
    {   
        float sum = cell[i] + cell[i + 1];
        cell[i + 1] = sum;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to do it using pointer like in your case:

```
void subtotal(float* cell, int n)
{

    for(int i(0); i < n - 1; i++)
    {   
        float sum = *(cell + i) + *(cell + i + 1);
        *(cell + i + 1) = sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a matter of style, I'd use `(int i = 1; i < n; i++)` and then write the body of the loop as `cell[i] += cell[i-1];` ... but it ends up the same.  I certainly would *not* declare `sum` outside the loop - I would object to that in a code review.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Yes I edited the code so that `sum` is scoped inside the loop. I wonder how I didn't notice that! Thanks.

Comment: @Raindrop7 - that sort of "D'oh" moment is *why* we have code reviews!

Answer (score 0):

You should do `j <= i` in the inner loop. If you don't do that, the first new element in the array will be zero (summing over no elements at all). For the second element, it will only sum over the first, which is 0 again. Etc.

In addition, your code is very non-idiomatic. The normal way to address an array element is cell[i], not *(cell+i), although both ways are possible for plain arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should be:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void subtotal(float*,int);

int main(void)
{
    int n = 5;
    float *cell=new float[n];
    cell[0] = 5.8f;
    cell[1] = 2.6f;
    cell[2] = 9.1f;
    cell[3] = 3.4f;
    cell[4] = 7.0f;
    subtotal(cell,n);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<*(cell+i)<<"|";
    delete []cell;  
}

void subtotal(float*cell,int n)
{
    float * temp = new float [n];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
        float sum=0;
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++) // Change here
        {
            sum+=*(cell+j); 
        }
        *(temp+i)=sum; // Change here
    }

    for (int i =0; i < n; ++i) {
       cell[i] = temp[i]; // Copy the values back
    }
    delete [] temp;
}
```

There are two problems with your subtotal function.

First, you should do `j <= i` in the inner loop.
Next, you should store the summation in a temporary array, else you are going to make changes to the original input after each subset sum and the output you will get will not be the desired one. You would have got output like this :

```
5.8|8.4|23.3|40.9|85.4|
```

However, with the changes I have proposed, you should get the desired output:

```
5.8|8.4|17.5|20.9|27.9|
```

[corrected-code-here](http://ideone.com/04XNOt)

Comment: Downvoted for encouraging the use of this O(n²) algorithm.  O(n) is actually simpler.  (Also don't approve of doing the OPs homework for him.)